Open XML SDK - The Content-Control text in header does not get updated
Let's say I have a content control that already exists in the header with the name Header. To change the text of this content control I have tried the below methods
Method1
var headerParts = document.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts;
foreach(var headerPart in headerParts) {
    var rootElemet = headerPart.RootElement.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(test => test.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<SdtAlias>().Val == "Header").FirstOrDefault();
    if(rootElemet != null) {
        var elementText = rootElemet.Descendants<Text>().ToList();
        var element = rootElemet.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault();
        element.Text = "Text changed";
        headerPart.Header.Save();
    }
}
document.Save();

Method 2
The solution provided in this question Update Content-Control Text in Header and Footer using Open XML SDK
Both of the methods does not update the text of the content control. Am I doing something wrong? Let me know your thoughts
Package used - DocumentFormat.OpenXml(2.16.0)

My guess is that you are not saving the changes to file. document.Save() does not save the changes to disk.
E.g.:
        byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("myDoc.docx");
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
            {
               // Do your changes on wordDoc
            }
            // Save the file - document.Save() does not save the changes to disk.
            File.WriteAllBytes("myDoc.docx", stream.ToArray());
        }


Yea tried this. It didn't work. My final approach was to delete the content control and recreate it
